# change size browser window

Tags: javascript, windows, browser, size

How can I change the size of the browser window? 
I tried like this:

```
   <!doctype html>
   <head>
<title>Index</title>
<!--<script>
   function changeScreenSize(w,h)
     {
       window.resizeTo( w,h )
     }
</script>-->
</head>   
<body onload="changeScreenSize(800,600) ">

<div id="container">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>hi</p>
    </div>

</body>  
</html>
```

but it only works with safari and the window is resizable. 
With other browsers it does not work

I have to create a 800x600 window not resizable and no scroll ... maybe without the edges of the browser

how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `resizeTo`, but it works only in newly created windows, as far as I know...

Its usage is heavily restricted by some browsers for obvious reasons.

```js
<script>
var window1;

function firstopen() {
    window1= window.open("", "", "width=100, height=100");
}

function thenresize() {
    window1.resizeTo(590, 590);
    window1.focus();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="firstopen()">open</button>
<button onclick="thenresize()">resize</button>
```